# How to prevent more than one application from opening the same file

Tags: c#, file-upload, file-locking

I have a windows service to upload file to different ftp site.

In order to speed up uploading, this service installed on 3 machines. Then problem occurs, because 3 services all look into same location to pick up file, sometimes they just pick up same file and then exception throws.

How to avoid such situation? the service designed by `.net 4.5` with `async` method, so if file lock applied, is performance will be slower?  I am thinking this way,

1. get all file names in directory
2. then lock this collection
3. somehow make sure each service get different sub collection, for example, 30 files total, then each service get 10.

but don't know how.

Comment: You can read a file without locking it.

Comment: How do these processes know a file needs to be sent?

Comment: You need a traffic cop, a single entity that decides what cars get to the cross the intersection.  A forth machine that distributes the jobs.  The very common name for such a machine is "server".

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file for exclusive read, if it fails it means another service currently processes it, then move to the next file.

```
File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: Good point. can this be done on directory level? For example, a folder called "AllOrders", and it contains many sub directories order1, order2 ... etc, each sub folder will contains text and images, basically I want to lock applied on order directory level, then doesn't matter how many services, each service will only pick up it own order and upload all files for this order.

Comment: will try like this Foreach (var dir in AllOrders){lock(dir){...}}

Comment: This does not work, no way to tell that another machine hasn't already taken care of the file and closed it again.

Comment: OK, a poor but worked solution is that once service get a folder, first to check if file "tmp.txt" exist or not, if exist skip upload files in this folder, if not, create a file called "tmp.txt" then continue. Because create file is exclusion, each services will work on different folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queue. It can be MSMQ or another service, which will load db Table with file names. Your other services can use some lock table.

You would have a table with a single record, which your service will call `update table t1 set t1.f1=t1.f1` in transaction. This will prevent other services from continuing.

In another table you have list of files and a flag if it is already taken.

Consider one service only reading these files and loading the file name table. 3 other services - end points, will lock the lock table record and then proceed to reading `n` file names and mark them as taken. Once files are loaded, file names can be deleted. 
If the service fails between taken and deleted: at the start of next process, check timestamp. If files were taken, lets say, yesterday and records still exist, may be they need to be processed again.

Comment: Files are text and images, and will be removed from IO once uploaded, so I don't want to database involved. will look into MSMQ. Thanks

Comment: I meant database only as means of tracking, not loading of files into it. Basically a home grown queue